# What are the simplest methods for the label noise problem?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, bert, transformer

If I have enough low quality data from unsupervised methods or rule-based methods.

I read from https://github.com/subeeshvasu/Awesome-Learning-with-Label-Noise ,but these methods are a little complex for me.

In detail, I deal with a multi-label classification task. First I crawl web page such as wiki and use regex-based rule to mark the label. The model input is the wiki title and the model output is the rule-matched labels from wiki content. My task is to predict the labels for the wiki title.

Do you think **removing the wrong data predicted by trained model** is a simple but effective method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the labeling people is sufficient,

the best solution is to re-label the noisy data.